# Node.js check mongoose validation and alert user

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

Hello I am using mongoose with the mongoose uniqure validator which is a module for easy mongoose validation.

I'd like to know the best way to go about this: when a user tries to submit a 'generator' with the same name as another 'generator', what is the best way to alert the user of this without having to reload the page, or at the least without having to reset their form data.

The validation side works, but I'm open to validate and alert in any other ways

```
exports.new = function(req,res){
///generator/new
res.render("new",{title:"New Generator"});
};

exports.create = function(req, res){

new Generator({
    name: req.body.name,
    words: req.body.words
}).save(function(err,docs){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        //This is where it returns validation errors.  
        //I am wondering the best way to alert the user of this.
    }else{
    res.redirect('/generators/'+docs.name);}
})
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method that I've used before is to use [`connect-flash`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) (this requires you to use sessions, though).

With it, you'd store 'flash messages' in the user's session which you can then show through your templating engine.

In your case, the code would look something like this:

```
// somewhere in your app setup
var flash = require('connect-flash');
...
app.use(flash());
...

// your routes:
exports.new = function(req, res) {
  res.render("new", {
    title   : "New Generator"
    errors  : req.flash('error') // pass all 'error' messages to template
  });
};

exports.create = function(req, res) {
  new Generator({
    name  : req.body.name,
    words : req.body.words
  }).save(function(err,docs){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      // store the error message as a flash message
      req.flash('error', err.message);
      // redirect back to /new
      res.redirect('/new');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/generators/' + docs.name);
    }
  })
};
```

So when saving triggers an error, the error is stored and the user is redirected back to the 'new' page. In your 'new' template you get a variable `errors`, containing an array (which can be empty), which you can use to present the error(s) to the user.